# read data from file to a 2d array [Python]

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a file .txt like this:

```
8.3713312149,0.806817531586,0.979428482338,0.20179159543
5.00263547897,2.33208847046,0.55745770379,0.830205341157
0.0087910592556,4.98708152771,0.56425779093,0.825598658777
```

and I want data to be saved in a 2d array such as

```
array = [[8.3713312149,0.806817531586,0.979428482338,0.20179159543],[5.00263547897,2.33208847046,0.55745770379,0.830205341157],[0.0087910592556,4.98708152771,0.56425779093,0.825598658777]
```

I tried with this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

checkpoints_from_file[][]

def read_checkpoints():
    global checkpoints_from_file
    with open("checkpoints.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            checkpoints_from_file.append(line.split(","))
        print checkpoints_from_file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_checkpoints()
```

but it does not work.
Can you guys tell me how to fix this? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors in your code. The first is that `checkpoints_from_file[][]` is not a valid way to initialize a multidimensional array in Python. Instead, you should write

```
checkpoints_from_file = []
```

This initializes a one-dimensional array, and you then append arrays to it in your loop, which creates a 2D array with your data.

You are also storing the entries in your array as strings, but you likely want them as floats. You can use the [float](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) function as well as a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to accomplish this.

```
checkpoints_from_file.append([float(x) for x in line.split(",")])
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from your file,

```
def read_checkpoints():
    checkpoints_from_file = []
    with open("checkpoints.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            checkpoints_from_file.append(line.split(","))
        print(checkpoints_from_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_checkpoints()
```

---

Or assuming you can read this data successfully, using a string literal,

```
lines = """8.3713312149,0.806817531586,0.979428482338,0.20179159543
5.00263547897,2.33208847046,0.55745770379,0.830205341157
0.0087910592556,4.98708152771,0.56425779093,0.825598658777"""
```

and a list comprehension,

```
list_ = [[decimal for decimal in line.split(",")] for line in lines.split("\n")]
```

Expanded,

```
checkpoints_from_file = []
for line in lines.split("\n"):
    list_of_decimals = []
    for decimal in line.split(","):
        list_of_decimals.append(decimal)
    checkpoints_from_file.append(list_of_decimals)

print(checkpoints_from_file)
```

---

**Your errors:**

1. Unlike in some languages, in Python you don't initialize a list like, `checkpoints_from_file[][]`, instead, you can initialize a one-dimensional list `checkpoint_from_file = []`. Then, you can insert more lists inside of it with Python's `list.append()`.